# How do I put keywords after abstract in amsart?

Tags: abstract, amsart, keywords

I'm using amsart and want to place keywords after abstract but amsart places them in the footnote. Does anyone know how Ι can override this? 
An example of the code I've been using:

```
\documentclass[12pt, reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{ amsthm, amscd, amsfonts, amssymb, graphicx,tikz, color, environ}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\title
\address
\date
\keywords
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please edit your answer to provide an example of the code you've tried using so far. Without it, it's difficult to give sufficiently precise advice.

Answer (score 21):

if you're submitting this article to the ams, even if you put the keywords *into* the abstract, they would be edited to put them into the first-page footnotes.  if you're just using the `amsart` class to prepare a preprint, then my suggestion is to start a new paragraph *within* the abstract, perhaps like this:

```
\smallskip
\noindent \textbf{Keywords.} list of keywords
```

by the way, `amssymb` automatically loads `amsfonts`, so that package doesn't need to be loaded separately.  also, for `amsart`, the abstract should go *before* `\maketitle`.

Comment: Instead of explicitly using "Keywords", one could also use `\keywordsname` to have the default "Key words and phrases".