# How to add keywords to this paper, after abstract

Tags: texmaker, keywords

I have tried several methods given on internet but nothing works. Can someone help. I am posting my preamble below. I am also fine with adding keywords in footnote, but if I can add them after abstract, it would be better.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage[latin2]{inputenc}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{epic}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage
[left=2.7cm,
right=3.0cm,
top=3.5cm,
bottom=4.0cm,]{geometry}
\usepackage{epstopdf} 
\def\numset#1{{\\mathbb #1}}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{Th}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{Lemma}[Th]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{Cor}[Th]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{Prop}[Th]{Proposition}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{Def}[Th]{Definition}
\newtheorem{Conj}[Th]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{Rem}[Th]{Remark}
\newtheorem{?}[Th]{Problem}
\newtheorem{Ex}[Th]{Example}

\newcommand{\im}{\operatorname{im}}
\newcommand{\Hom}{{\rm{Hom}}}
\newcommand{\diam}{{\rm{diam}}}
\newcommand{\ovl}{\overline}
%\newcommand{\M}{\mathbb{M}}


\begin{document}

\title{dddfdgs}

\author{sds Ssdasgh}
\author{Basdishth}




\address{se \\ University of dsdsDshid
\email{dssdasdsogy@gmail.com}
\address{Univsasa\\ Deparsastics}
\email{sadr@gmail.com}


\begin{abstract} lipsum
\end{abstract}



\maketitle


\section{Introduction} blablbalab

\end{document}
```

Comment: `amsart` provides the `\keywords{}`.

Comment: @Sigur ok thanks. it puts them in footnote. I am fine with it. Also can you tell if I can make heading of a  section bold? Like "Introduction", by itself, is written in a normal, non bold way.

Comment: The format of `\section` depends on the class you use. In `amsart` the default is upper case and centered, if I remember. You can use `article` class, for example, but in this case I think you lost `\keywords`.

Comment: Take a look at [How do I put keywords after abstract in amsart?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57793/579)  (potential duplicate).